# Query grouped by two swap fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have collection `messages` with the following documents

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5164218f359f109fd4000012"),
  "receiver_id" : ObjectId("5164211e359f109fd4000004"),
  "sender_id" : ObjectId("5162de8a359f10cbf700000c"),
  "body" : "Hello Billy!!!",
  "readed" : false,
  "updated_at" : ISODate("2013-04-09T14:11:27.17Z"),
  "created_at" : ISODate("2013-04-09T14:11:27.17Z")
}
```

I need to make query for receive last messages(don't matter recieved or sended) for a given user (grouped by reciever_id+sender_id fields) and sorted by created_at.

To better explain the question, an example of how I did it in SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (sender_id+receiver_id) * FROM messages 
    ORDER by (sender_id+receiver_id), created_at DESC
    WHERE sender_id = given_user or receiver_id = given_user
```

I don't understand how to solve this problem with mondodb.

Answer (score 2):

The [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2+ provides the most obvious translation of your query.  The MongoDB manual includes an [SQL to Aggregation Framework Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) as a general guide, although there are definite differences in the two approaches.

Here's a commented example you can try in the `mongo` shell:

```
var given_user = ObjectId("5162de8a359f10cbf700000c");
db.messages.aggregate(
    // match: WHERE sender_id = given_user or receiver_id = given_user
    // NB: do the match first, because it can take advantage of an available index
    { $match: {
        $or:[
            { sender_id: given_user },
            { receiver_id: given_user },
        ]
    }},

    { $group: {
        //  DISTINCT ON (sender_id+receiver_id)
        _id: { sender_id: "$sender_id", receiver_id: "$receiver_id" }
    }},

    // ORDER by (sender_id+receiver_id), created_at DESC
    { $sort: {
        sender_id: 1,
        receiver_id: 1,
        created_at: -1
    }}
)
```

Sample result:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "sender_id" : ObjectId("5162de8a359f10cbf700000c"),
                "receiver_id" : ObjectId("5164211e359f109fd4000004")
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You may want to add additional fields on the grouping, such as a count of messages received.

If you actually want to combine the sender_id+receiver_id into a single field, you can use the [`$concat`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#exp._S_concat) operator in MongoDB 2.4+.

Comment: In situation when given_user not just send, but receive some messages too. Group does not work as needed, because fields(sender_id,receiver_id) for given_user a swaped, and this born new entity in the result.

Comment: For this reason, I used `sender_id+receiver_id` in SQL.

Comment: If you are matching given_user as either `sender_id` or `receiver_id`, this will cover the case of that user sending or receiving messages and should be equivalent to your SQL query.  The grouped output will differentiate between the case where the same two users are exchanging emails: `{sender_id: user1, receiver_id: user2}` vs `{sender_id: user2, receiver_id: user1}. If you actually want unique pairs your SQL query would need to be changed as well.

Comment: My SQL example work as expected, because in SQL id is integer. Thank you anyway for a good solution that help me understand some things.

Comment: Btw, how do you think, if I change structure to embedded `users:{sender_id: "5162de8a359f10cbf700000c", receiver_id: "5162de8a359f10cbf7000004"}`. Is this helps me? mb with check like  `is given_user in ...`.

Comment: So to be clear .. for the output you just want to find the distinct users that `given_user` has exchange messages with ?

Comment: Yes, distinct users with last messages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit way to do so. Let's review workarounds:

Way 1:
do the distinct at code level (after find), then just use `find`:

```
db.message.find({$or:[{sender_id:?}, {receiver_id:?}]})
```

Way 2:Using aggregation framework :

```
db.message.aggregate( [
   {$match: {$or:[{sender_id:?}, {receiver_id:?}]},
    $group: { _id: {sender:"$sender_id", receiver:"$receiver_id"},
               other: { ... } } },
   $sort: {sender_id,receiver_id,...}
   ] )
```

This way problem appears at sort level since `sender_id, receiver_id`  is not the same as `sender_id+receiver_id`

Way 3: Introduce the surrogate field sender_id+receiver_id then use `find` or even `distinct` per Stennie hint.

Comment: With your way #3 and a surrogate field, you could actually use the [distinct()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) command on that field instead of a `find()`.

Comment: Way #2 with `$group: { _id: {sender:"$sender_id", receiver:"$receiver_id"}}` seems does not work because when fields swaped, its make new entity in result.

Comment: @ole - you don't need swap the fields, so even if sender is null then key will be the same `{null, ObjectId("5164211e359f109fd4000004")}`